# Add more filters in report the products ordered

Tags: admin, magento-1.6, reports

Here I am giving my first steps in magento.

And I came across a nescessidade

in: Reports-> Products-> Products ordered

Has the following filters:

[image]

Would add a new filter, such as that in: Reports-> Sales-> Orders

[image]

Is that possible? 
If yes, could someone give me some help? I did a search for extension or someone with similar problems but not getting suceso, I'll be grateful for any guidance.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I've written a custom extension for one my clients who needed to filter Reports->Sales->Orders by custom channels i.e. eBay, Amazon, etc. to see sales/profits from those channels. I'll salvage some of the code to help you out once I get home.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030255/how-to-create-a-report-in-magento/7032477#7032477